# Website HTML page links result in 404 errors

Tags: html, cpanel, http-status-code-404

I've made a website using html and uploaded it to cpanel, it was working fine on the preview but now that I have activated the nameservers and made it available for anyone to see, the links to other pages like "contact us" and "about" no longer work.

I've checked the urls in the html and it's all correct, even renamed the pages and changed the urls to match and nothing has worked so far, I just get 404 errors.
Would be really grateful for any help.

This is the code for links on the homepage:

```
<li>
     <a href="/home/cpanelUsername/public_html/about.html">About</a>
</li>
```

Comment: if the website is live can you link to it as it's a lot easier to troubleshoot that way. unfortunately there isn't a lot we can do with the information provided :/

Comment: @DavidGolding Hi, thanks for the response, actually think I have just found the solution, will check now and get back to you

Comment: Please could you add some code?

Comment: @Burgi so the links I have on the homepage are like this in html:  

<li><a href="/home/cpanelUsername/public_html/about.html">About</a></li>

and the file structure on cpanel is is the same, I've tried adding subdomains but that didn't work either, thanks!

Comment: @DavidGolding wouldn't let me add you in the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your links are incorrect.

From the end user's point of view every folder above `/public_html/` is invisible and cannot be accessed through normal operation.

You should try the following:

```
<li>
   <a href="about.html">About</a>
</li>
```

The web server will search the current directory looking for a file called `about.html` and link to that.

Comment: Thanks, just worked it out, got http://www.about.websitename.com/ to work well